# Minimum of a Polynomial in Python

Tags: code-golf, tips, python, optimization, polynomials

What is the shortest amount of code that can find the minimum of an inputted polynomial? I realize that you can import packages like Numpy and others, but using only user defined functions, what is the shortest way to do this? For example, if 6x<sup>6</sup> + 4x<sup>3</sup>-12 is entered (ignore parsing issues), what would be the shortest amount of code to find the minimum value?

Comment: Does "ignore parsing issues" mean that we can assume the polynomial data is in any convenient form?  E.g. can I accept the example polynomial as a list of coefficients `[-12, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6]`?

Comment: What should be the output for polynomials whose minimum value is negative infinity, such as x^3?

Comment: @DLosc yes that is acceptable, and I guess I should exclude those that don't have a finite number. Let's assume they exist in the space of R2, and are rational numbers.

Comment: Is a local minimum acceptable ?

Comment: @Mig yes, but  ideally the program will find all minima and select the smallest one (not just magnitude, so -100 is lower than -2).

Answer (score 6):

### Python - 202 Bytes

```python
D=lambda p:[i*p[i]for i in range(1,len(p))]
A=lambda p,x:p>[]and p[0]+x*A(p[1:],x)
def N(p):f=D(p);s=D(f);x=1.;y=-x;exec'x-=A(f,x)/A(s,x);y-=A(f,y)/A(s,y);'*99;return A(p,x),A(p,y)
print min(N(input()))
```

*11 bytes saved due to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50777?noredirect=1#comment120139_50780).*

Input is taken from stdin, and is expected to be in the following format: [*x<sup>0</sup>*, *x<sup>1</sup>*, *x<sup>2</sup>*, ...]. For example, the sample in the problem description would be entered as `[-12, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6]`.

---

**Functions**

*D* - Calculates the derivative of a polynomial *p*.
*A* - Applies a polynomial *p* to the value *x*.
*N* - Uses Newton's Method to calculate local minima/maxima of a polynomial *p*.

*Note:* For higher order polynomials, there may be several local minima. In these cases, this function is not guaranteed to find the global minimum.

---

**Sample Usage**

```python
$ echo [-12, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6] | python poly-min.py
-12.6666666667
```

Comment: I think you can do the polynomial evaluation shorter recursively: `A=lambda p,x:p>[]and p[0]+x*A(p[1:],x)`.

Comment: How do you guarantee that Newton's method converges?

Comment: @PeterTaylor if the first derivative isn't zero anywhere, for example _x³ + x_, it obviously won't. But this also implies that there isn't a local minimum anywhere, either.

Comment: I was more interested in the case where there *is* a local minimum, but Newton's method [goes in circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Starting_point_enters_a_cycle).